# Como setar --no-ri --no-rdoc como default ao usar o gem install?

Tags: ruby, gem

Sempre ao dar o gem install tenho que fornecer os parametros --no-ri e --no-rdoc, gostaria que isso fosse padrão para esse comando!

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um arquivo .gemrc no seu home, com as opções que você quer passar para todos os comandos "gem" por padrão:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Comment: você também pode usar


`gem: --no-document`

Answer (score 3):

Uma alternativa mais genérica à solução do jpkrohling é definir um alias no seu terminal. No bash, por exemplo, você pode adicionar o seguinte no seu arquivo .bash_profile:

```
alias gi="gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc"
```

Com isso o atalho `gi [gem]` passa a ficar disponível.

Answer (score 0):

Vá ao terminal e digite:

```shell
$ which gem
```

Isto vai te dizer em qual diretório está o executável do gem. Abra-o com um editor. Provavelmente ele vai ser algo assim:

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['GEM_HOME']=ENV['GEM_HOME'] || '/Users/Ecil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1'
ENV['GEM_PATH']=ENV['GEM_PATH'] || '/Users/Ecil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1:/Users/Ecil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1@global'
ENV['PATH']='/Users/Ecil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1/bin:/Users/Ecil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-rc1@global/bin:/Users/Ecil/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-rc1/bin:' + ENV['PATH']

#--
# Copyright 2006 by Chad Fowler, Rich Kilmer, Jim Weirich and others.
# All rights reserved.
# See LICENSE.txt for permissions.
#++

require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
require 'rubygems/exceptions'

required_version = Gem::Requirement.new ">= 1.8.7"

unless required_version.satisfied_by? Gem.ruby_version then
  abort "Expected Ruby Version #{required_version}, is #{Gem.ruby_version}"
end

args = ARGV.clone

begin
  Gem::GemRunner.new.run args
rescue Gem::SystemExitException => e
  exit e.exit_code
end
```

Modifique a atribuição `args = ARGV.clone` para concatenar os argumentos da linha de comando com o `--no-ri` e o `--no-rdoc`.

Não testei esta solução mas acredito que funcione.

Comment: Alterar diretamente scripts só deve ser feito como última alternativa… Além de abrir espaço para bugs, ainda corre o risco de perder a alteração na próxima atualização da gema.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um arquivo chamado `gemrc` onde é possível especificar o default. Tu podes por tanto no `~/.gemrc` quanto no `/etc/gemrc` (este caminho pode variar de distro para distro) a seguinte linha:

`gem: --no-document`